# mySQL dump inconsistency

Tags: mysql, indexing, export, dump

I have a structure only export on two databases, and use them to compare the schemas of my dev and production servers.

One of my fields has an index.

When I export the two sql files, in one file the index is defined like this :

```
 KEY `assoc_id` (`assoc_id`),
```

And in the other one like this :

```
  KEY `assoc_id` (`assoc_id`) USING BTREE,
```

The production server is a clone of the dev server, same version of mysql.

The export is done using Navicat (OS X) but I don't know if this is relevant since dump is native to mysql...

It's not a problem because both are btree in all cases, but I'm just curious to know why sometimes `USING BTREE` is added and sometimes not.

Edit :
Just saw the same thing with this : `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtually all indexes in MySQL are BTree.  The default for InnoDB and MyISAM Engines is BTree.  FULLTEXT and SPATIAL indexes also exist, but would be explicitly stated.  MEMORY Engine and NDB Cluster have other exceptions, such as HASH.

Therefore, `USING BTREE` is redundant and optional.  Nothing to worry about.

Possibly the difference stems from two different export products or versions.

Comment: I'll have a look on versions of everything, but both servers being cloned virtual machines I don't see how their versions could be differents.

Comment: MySQL version 5.5.44 everywhere... I don't understand.